# How can the event listener always get the newest state value in a function component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I am using this code to store the user input index value, the event listener always gets the initial value, 0. Here is a reproduction code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

const Chat: React.FC = (props) => {

  const [currInputIndex, setCurrInputIndex] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    initialCurrentSelect();
    handleKeyboardEvent();
}, []);

const initialCurrentSelect = async () =>{
    setCurrInputIndex(1);
}

const handleKeyboardEvent = () => {
  const handleKeyUp = async (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
          const selected = currInputIndex - 1;
          console.log(selected);
      }
  };
  window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keyup",handleKeyUp);
  };
}

  return (<div></div>);
}

export default Chat;
```

When I run this code after the page completes and I press the key-down. The key-down function gets the value 0, not 1. Why the event listener could not get the newest value? What should I do to fix this issue? I have tried to pass the parameter like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

const Chat: React.FC = (props) => {

  const [currInputIndex, setCurrInputIndex] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    initialCurrentSelect();
    handleKeyboardEvent();
}, []);

const initialCurrentSelect = async () =>{
    setCurrInputIndex(1);
}

const handleKeyboardEvent = () => {
  const handleKeyUp = ( inputIndex: number) => async (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
          const selected = inputIndex - 1;
          console.log(selected);
      }
  };
  window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp(currInputIndex));
  return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keyup",handleKeyUp(currInputIndex));
  };
}

  return (<div></div>);
}

export default Chat;
```

But still did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `initialCurrentSelect` only to call `setCurrInputIndex(1)` on mount. You can give `1` as a parameter to `useState`.

Then to have the most up-to-date state in your event handler, you can add it to the dependency array of your `useEffect`, like so:

```
const Chat: React.FC = (props) => {
  const [currInputIndex, setCurrInputIndex] = useState(1); 

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyUp = async (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
        const selected = currInputIndex - 1;
        console.log(selected);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    };
  }, [currInputIndex]);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: why need to rebind the event every time the state change? @Youssouf Oumar

Comment: If the dependency array is empty, the callback of the event is registered once in memory, and `currInputIndex` is passed as a value that is not tied to your state anymore. With  `currInputIndex` in the dependency array, we clear the old one and register a new one with the up-to-date state.

Comment: If you want to understand in depth why it's like this, you can read this [article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov.